# Solving the 2nd-Order Linear Non-Homogeneous Differential equation $y''-y=4\sinh x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given equation:

$$y''-y=4 \sinh x$$ with initial values $y(0)=2$ and $y'(0)=2$

I solved the 2nd order non-homogeneous differential equation and I got my final equation as $y=e^{x}+e^{-x}+2x \cosh x$

Would this be correct?

Comment: Notice that $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$  can be multiplied by arbitrary constants since they span the homogenous solution space

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: the solution space is $$\{x\mapsto C_1 e^x + C_2 e^{-x}+2 x\cosh x:C_1,C_2\in\mathbb R\}$$ i. e. $$y(x)=C_1 e^x + C_2 e^{-x}+2 x\cosh x$$ where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants

Comment: You posted almost the same question one hour ago? Why did you open a new question?

Comment: Please consult a book about ordinary differential equations and look for equations of order 2 and their theory. Many authors have written about that special case.